# which calendar to use that has data extraction API?

Tags: php, python, google-calendar-api

I am making an application that lets your phone connect and control your calendar. I was initially going to use Google calendar because of its cool Python API but quickly got discouraged after reading the downtime issues which still persist. I didnt choose the php library because it requires you to download Zend framework which I don't want so I am sticking to the python library but anything that doesn't require me to download frameworks is fine with me.

Can someone provide the overall yearly downtime for Google Calendar or suggest me to an alternative calendar which has data extraction and modification API's that is similar to Google Calendar but more reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at http://www.google.com/appsstatus#do=54&hl=en you can see the downtime information for the last two months. There are no problems at all listed for Google Calendar. A search for calendar downtime almost exclusively returns results from previous years, suggesting things have become more reliable.

In addition, Google Calendar is one of the apps included in the Google Apps TOS, http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/terms/sla.html, where they guarantee 99.9% uptime against free days of service.

This would suggest that while some people have had trouble in the past, the service overall is reliable. I don't think anything like a yearly downtime report is available.

If you're looking for alternatives to Google Calendar, see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9429/alternative-to-google-calendar which asks the same question.

Comment: thanks a lot, i had already accessed the SLA so I know about that but the 2 month link of downtime you posted is very helpful to my decision, thanks a lot.